Android cookies for external browser
anyone knows how to set the cookies to external browser from android applications?
#android #developement
I tried with intent and custom chrome tab it is not working .
Is there any script Java option present.
Our main motive is to auto login in external browser from android application.
We want to pass the cookies from app to web browser.

I don't know this for sure, but I doubt this is possible. It would be a huge security hole if apps could get/set cookies in the internet browser just like that.

I don't think you could automate setting the cookie via your Java code but you can probably go a more roundabout manner where basically your Android app opens up the browser to a URL that has a token inside it, the web app reads and validates the token (some signature mechanism) and sets the appropriate cookies to authenticate the user. This obviously is quite an involved process where both the Android app and the web app will need to co-operate properly and securely.

Do you know any JavaScript option?

Here is the code for setting up cookies for an external browser in to your app.
You can chage the values as per your requirement in cookieString
binding.webview.setCookiesEnabled(true)
binding.webview.setThirdPartyCookiesEnabled(true)

val cookieManager = CookieManager.getInstance()
val cookieString =
            "UserAutoLoginToken=${sharedPref.loginToken}; Domain=${YourDomain}; Path=/; Secure; Expires=${System.currentTimeMillis() + 86400000}"
cookieManager.setCookie(YourBaseURL, cookieString)


We need to achieve this without web view
